# How to hide or encrypt the URL of custom pages

Tags: php, wordpress, url, encryption

How can I hide or encrypt the URL of custom pages in WordPress?

In my case I have one folder, with a lot of sub-folders, files, images, etc. When I access those pages, it will show the full path of file or folder URL in address bar. The end user can easily access pages by using URL shown in address bar, which I think is not secure.

Comment: Do you want the user to access the files in this folder or not?

Comment: No its not secure for me, It access who's only know the file or folder path

Comment: Obfuscating the url is at the end just security by obscurity, the end user can still just access the "real" url. You should move the files out of the public domain so they're no longer publically accessible. Then you should have some kind of file table with a lookup hash and a path/filename. Then you can easily create a route (with ACL) that serves a file by its matching hash.

Comment: Still not sure about what you need ... if you don't want anyone to access the files outside of your wordpress you should put a .htaccess file in that folder and deny all incoming requests. When you want to open an element then you will need to include or require it via php / wordpress directly. You could however not reference an image directly then.

Comment: how i can perform this by using .htaccess file

Comment: @frank no one can access these files it only access who knows its directory path, is it possible by using .htaccess file...plz guide me

Comment: See that guide : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If nobody should be able to open the resources directly you can create a file in this folder and simply call it '.htaccess'. Within this file you simply put

```
Deny from all
```

That's it - nobady can open the resources. If there's a script for example you could include it using php

```
<?php
include '/path/to/my/protexted/directory/script.php';
// Some for require etc.
```

If someone should still be able to open this specific source file via url you could think about a simple password protection using htaccess and htpasswd

Refer to this for more info regarding this:

http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

http://www.htaccesstools.com/htaccess-authentication/

Be sure to read through both parts: htaccess and htpasswd

If you want very special links / encryption you could use a database to store generated strings / hashes and the path to the file. These would be the example step to achieve this:

1. User Opens URL like mypage.dev/hiddenContent?hash=231n1
2. You read the hash and the matching path (following db example)

   ```
   id | hash  | path
   1    231n1   'my/hidden/file.img'
   ```
3. You open the file via require

   ```
   <?php
   include($path);
   ```

Hope this somewhat helps

Answer (score 0):

1. first you go to wp-content->Themes->functions.php
2. Then remove **add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );**
3. Now reload your site and check address bar.